# edit list in python removing comma inside round brackets and the round brackets too

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to do an application that picks up the temperature from the database and shows on matplotlib graphic but I have a problem with the temperature from the database.

indeed when I "download" the temperature from the database the output is [(29.0,), (27.9,), (27.9,), (27.9,), (27.9,)] and I want data without the comma inside round brackets and the round brackets too.

this is my code:

````
import database

#VARIABILI GLOBALI
x= []
y= [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50]

numero= int(input("Quanti prelievi bisogna fare: "))

database.mycursor.execute("select Temperature from Sensore1 order by id desc limit "+str(numero))
prelievi= database.mycursor.fetchall()
print(prelievi) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Try this to convert the list:

```
data = [(29.0,), (27.9,), (27.9,), (27.9,), (27.9,)]

converted = [x[0] for x in data]
```

Comment: `[x for i in data for x in i]` is better for many situations.

Comment: Of course but he said that he has this specific structure so we dont need to call another loop for that.

Comment: I'm not criticizing your answer, simply adding an alternative in the comment that may be helpful for others, since an entirely new answer here would be redundant.

Comment: Yeah that's true and I did not feel that way, just wanted to make clear why I would choose the way I wrote in my answer over your way for his specific use case. But you are right, for more than one tuple objects your snippet is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses are tuples. You can chain them if you want:

```
from itertools import chain
l1 = [(29.0,), (27.9,), (27.9,), (27.9,), (27.9,)]
r = list(chain.from_iterable(l1))
print(r) # [29.0, 27.9, 27.9, 27.9, 27.9]
```

You can also use list comprehension but using the itertools chain call is a little more dynamic.

Alternatively:

```
l1 = [(29.0,), (27.9,), (27.9,), (27.9,), (27.9,)]
r = [ele for tup in l1 for ele in tup]
print(r) # [29.0, 27.9, 27.9, 27.9, 27.9]
```

Comment: it doesn't work, now the error is "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3,) and (11,)".

Comment: Are you using a numpy array? Thats not an error you get with lists and tuples.